# Not Getting proper result code in onActivityForResult

Tags: android, android-intent

In my app there is a share functionality, we do startActivityForResult using Intent.createChooser()  with the ACTION_SEND. When we choose gmail app for sharing the compose activity is launched and from that screen if we press back or if we send mail we get same response code. Hence my app is not able to identify whether user has sent the mail or just came back from there.

Thanks in Advance for the help.

Comment: pleas post the relevant code..

Answer (score 0):

You can't identify whether the user actually sends the email using `StartActivityForResult`, only that the user went to the email application and then returned from it.

Answer (score 0):

The applications which handle ACTION_SEND have to implement a resultCode to return

In your case I don't think the eMail clients implement a resultCode in return

Just check resultCode in debug to be sure